# Image is not taking full screen with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a Image which I want that takes the whole screen but is leaving some white space at the top and at the left side of the screen and I don't know why is doing it. I attached the code of it.

```css
img {
background: 0px 0px / 100% 100% no-repeat scroll rgb(12, 12, 12);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.morefree.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/black-wallpaper-01.jpg">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this css line:

```
body{margin:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mm08hruf/

Comment: Thank you I was adding that rule to the img rule but it didn't do anything now I see that I had to add it to the body rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the margin on the body.

```css
/* margin reset */
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  background: 0px 0px / 100% 100% no-repeat scroll rgb(12, 12, 12);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.morefree.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/black-wallpaper-01.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
html,body{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```